# Weird characters in console when loading tidyverse

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I face the following output after loading the tidyverse:
[image: tidyverse console output]

Why are these characters being displayed? This is the first time that this happens.

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3 tools_4.1.3
```

Comment: My guess is that it is encoding for the check mark. Maybe restart and update? Or maybe check what the current encoding is: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding-in-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: Interesting. I have the same issue on a German computer (Windows).

Comment: Yes, is the check mark. The problem remains after reinstalling tidyverse and restarting Rstudio.

Comment: This appears to be a known and open issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/256. It would be safe to ignore the symbol for now.